# Trying to call custom class

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey fellow programmers....first I'd like to say I had this working before I tried to import it into a my main class but now its broke....I'm just trying to get this `productselection class` linked and working in `barrelbuilder class` thank you very much in advance for any help as I just loop through difFerent errors trying to fix it.

```
BarrelBuilder.as
package  {

import flash.net.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.xml.*;
import utils.ProductSelection;


public class BarrelBuilder extends MovieClip{

    var PSelection:ProductSelection;

public function BarrelBuilder():void
    {

        PSelection.ProductSelection();

    }
}

}


ProductSelection.as 

package utils 
{

import flash.net.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.xml.*;


public class ProductSelection extends MovieClip{
    private static var columns:Number;
    private static var my_x:Number;
    private static var my_y:Number;
    private static var my_thumb_width:Number;
    private static var my_thumb_height:Number;
    private static var my_images:XMLList;
    private static var my_total:Number;

    private static var container_mc:MovieClip;

    private static var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();



    public static function ProductSelections(stage:Object){
    init(stage);

    }

    public static function init(stage:Object)
    {
        myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("resources.xml"));
        myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML(stage));


        function processXML (e:Event):void{
            var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

            columns = myXML.@COLUMNS;
            my_x = myXML.@XPOSITION;
            my_y = myXML.@YPOSITION;
            my_thumb_width = myXML.@WIDTH;
            my_thumb_height = myXML.@HEIGHT;
            my_images = myXML.IMAGE;
            my_total = my_images.length();

            createContainer(stage);
            callThumbs();

            }
    }
    public static function createContainer(stage:Object):void{
        container_mc = new MovieClip();
        container_mc.x = my_x;
        container_mc.y = my_y;
        //container_mc.height = 50;
        //container_mc.width = 140;
        stage.addChild(container_mc);
    }
    public static function callThumbs():void{
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++){

        var thumb_url = my_images[i].@THUMB;;
        var thumb_loader = new Loader();
        thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
        thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

        thumb_loader.x = (my_thumb_width+10)*i;
        }
    }
    public static function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void{
        var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
        container_mc.addChild(my_thumb);
        //my_thumb.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, thumb_Clicked);
    }

    //thumbClicked()
    //{

    //}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PSelection = new ProductSelection(stage);
```

Will work if BarrelBuilder is your "**Main**" class.

**If not**:

```
public function BarrelBuilder():void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAddedToStage)
}
private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    PSelection = new ProductSelection(stage);
}
```

See my basic explanation of initializing classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529062/how-to-return-a-variable-from-public-function/17529255#17529255)