# Access public method located in .as class file from timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the source code of this example.
Now I wanted to send the Byte Array from the swf to JavaScript.

I have just learnt how to use ExternalInterface in order to call functions back and forth from JS <=> AS3

everything is working fine.

But all AS3 code I've written was on the first frame of the flash file, not in the .as class file. (this class extends MovieClip not Sprite)

after testing I wanted to add it to the .as class files to get the data from in there. It doesn't work.
Is the only way is to convert everything in the class to static so i can access it from outside? (AS3 in the frames)

Comment: Do you want to access some method located in your .as class from timelime?

Comment: I guess yes from timeline. (I'm not familiar with the terminology). I pressed F9 while I was in the first frame. That's where the code accessing the method is written.

Comment: "From timeline" I meant from any frame in your .fla project instead of from .as class file. UPD: from your update I see that the answer is "Yes" you call it from timeline.

Comment: Have you tried to initialize your outside class in your frame? See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529062/how-to-return-a-variable-from-public-function/17529255#17529255 BUT, if you have a method, that perfoms something simple and you want to use it from everywere than it is good to make it static, so you can do it.

Comment: @ZuzEL i don't get how I can. I wanted without static. Also, there's an instance somewhere, but I didn't initialize it anywhere. The class extends MovieClip and deals with buttons in the fla. Is it safe to construct another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can not access for methods located in separate files from your timeline.

1. Instead transfer(copy-paste) all code, that you have in your frame to newly
   created *Main.as* class.
2. Choose this class as a base class for your project.
3. Make sure your imports are outside class{} scope.

   ```
   package {

       //imports
       import flash.display.MovieClip;
       import flash.display.Shape;

       public class Main extends MovieClip
       {
           public function Main()
           {
               //code from frame excluding imports
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks I think that would work. What I have done is take the code in the .as file and past it into the timeline and it worked too!

Comment: Yes it works in both sides. But try to avoid placing your code in timeline.